# R concentrating data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, iteration

I have a data frame like this

```
>X_com
  Day_1 Day_2 Day_3 Day_4 Day_5 Day_6 Day_7 Day_8 Day_9 Day_10
1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      1
2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0
3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0
4     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0
5     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0
6     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0
7     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0
8     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0
```

I need to concentrate all the values into one column and add another column with "1;"
So I did this

```
> X_new=matrix(1,8,2)
> X_new[1,]=paste(X_com[1,1], X_com[1,2],X_com[1,3],X_com [1,4],X_com[1,5],X_com[1,6],X_com[1,7],X_com[1,8],X_com [1,9],X_com[1,10], sep="")
> X_new[2,]=paste(X_com[2,1], X_com[2,2],X_com[2,3],X_com [2,4],X_com[2,5],X_com[2,6],X_com[2,7],X_com[2,8],X_com [2,9],X_com[2,10], sep="")
> X_new[3,]=paste(X_com[3,1], X_com[3,2],X_com[3,3],X_com [3,4],X_com[3,5],X_com[3,6],X_com[3,7],X_com[3,8],X_com [3,9],X_com[3,10], sep="")
> X_new[4,]=paste(X_com[4,1], X_com[4,2],X_com[4,3],X_com [4,4],X_com[4,5],X_com[4,6],X_com[4,7],X_com[4,8],X_com [4,9],X_com[4,10], sep="")
> X_new[5,]=paste(X_com[5,1], X_com[5,2],X_com[5,3],X_com [5,4],X_com[5,5],X_com[5,6],X_com[5,7],X_com[5,8],X_com [5,9],X_com[5,10], sep="")
> X_new[6,]=paste(X_com[6,1], X_com[6,2],X_com[6,3],X_com [6,4],X_com[6,5],X_com[6,6],X_com[6,7],X_com[6,8],X_com [6,9],X_com[6,10], sep="")
> X_new[7,]=paste(X_com[7,1], X_com[7,2],X_com[7,3],X_com [7,4],X_com[7,5],X_com[7,6],X_com[7,7],X_com[7,8],X_com [7,9],X_com[7,10], sep="")
> X_new[8,]=paste(X_com[8,1], X_com[8,2],X_com[8,3],X_com [8,4],X_com[8,5],X_com[8,6],X_com[8,7],X_com[8,8],X_com [8,9],X_com[8,10], sep="")
> X_new[1:8,2]="1;"
> as.data.frame(X_new)
          V1 V2
1 0000000001 1;
2 0000000000 1;
3 0000000000 1;
4 0000000000 1;
5 0000000000 1;
6 0000000000 1;
7 0000000000 1;
8 0000000000 1;
```

I believe there's definitely a faster way of achieving this but have no clue.

The other problem is, I have over a thousand of data frame like this needs to be concentrated. I'm still learning how to loop these repetitive steps but is progressing quite slowly. If the original data frames were named uniquely, does that mean I have no choice but to work on each of them individually?

Answer (score 2):

The crux of your problem can be solved with `apply(x, 1, paste0, collapse = "")`

For example:

```
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1, 100, TRUE), ncol = 10))
apply(x, 1, paste0, collapse = "")
####
 [1] "1010001111" "1110001101" "1100100000" "0111000110" "0111101000" "0101100100"
 [7] "1110100110" "1001100010" "1101111011" "1101001111"
```

You may want to put this into a function since it sounds like you have many data.frames to `lapply` this to:

```
foo <- function(data, val) {
  collapse <- apply(data, 1, paste0, collapse = "")
  out <- data.frame(collapse, val)
  return(out)
  }

> foo(x,1)
     collapse val
1  1010001111   1
2  1110001101   1
3  1100100000   1
----
```

Answer (score 0):

I make no assurances about speed on this:

```
dat <- read.table(text = " Day_1 Day_2 Day_3 Day_4 Day_5 Day_6 Day_7 Day_8 Day_9 Day_10
+ 1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      1
+ 2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0
+ 3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0
+ 4     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0
+ 5     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0
+ 6     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0
+ 7     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0
+ 8     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0",header = TRUE,sep = "")
> data.frame(V1 = apply(dat,1,paste0,collapse = ""),V2 = "1;")
          V1 V2
1 0000000001 1;
2 0000000000 1;
3 0000000000 1;
4 0000000000 1;
5 0000000000 1;
6 0000000000 1;
7 0000000000 1;
8 0000000000 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted the original question but accidentally deleted that account. So I can't comment on the answers.

Just wanna say thank you.

Also I guess part of your code should be edited where "paste0" should be replaced as "paste"?

```
collapse <- apply(data, 1, paste, collapse = "")
```

Also the last column I need is "1:", and the function you created also work as:

```
> foo(x, "1;")
     collapse val
1  0010111000  1;
2  0000110001  1;
3  1100100101  1;
4  1100011100  1;
5  1111001101  1;
6  1100000111  1;
7  0001001001  1;
8  1110000011  1;
9  1011011101  1;
10 1111111000  1;
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: If you dont have paste0 then you are running an older version of R.

Comment: Oh! I am running 2.13.1 which is an older version. Will paste and paste0 do different things in my case? (I am reluctant to keep updating my R because the main package i'm using always have problem with newer version of R).